# my question is about inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A^2=I_n$, find $A^{-1}$.

a)  $A^4$
b)  $A^2$
c)  $A$ 
d)  There is insufficient information.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Try to write down the definition of "inverse matrix of a square matrix". Simple *understanding* that definition makes this problem completely trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$A^2=I_n$$ pre multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides, gives $$A=A^{-1}$$

Comment: strictly speaking you are using the fact that the inverse exists before you show that the inverse exists.

Comment: Yes absolutely correct because after finding the answer this way, we can check it by substituting it in the equation which here satisfies the equation. Here seeing the level of the question, this seems to be the right way.

Comment: maybe you shuold observe that $det(A^2)=det(A)\cdot det(A)=1\implies det(A)\neq0$ thus $A^{-1}$ exists

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^2 = I_{n}$, so $AA = I_{n}$, we have $A^{-1} = A$ by definition.